# Key refused in Sublime SFTP, but works in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, sftp, sublime-text

I've been using the SFTP package on Sublime Text to connect to AWS EC2 instances for a few years now and I've never had any problems. Today I created a new instance and for some reason I'm having trouble connecting to it.

When I try to connect to any other instance, the connection works. When I try to connect using PuTTY, the connection also works. It's only when I try to connect via Sublime Text that the problem happens.

**sftp-config.json:**

```
{
    "type": "sftp",

    "save_before_upload": true,
    "upload_on_save": true,
    "sync_down_on_open": true,
    "sync_skip_deletes": false,
    "sync_same_age": true,
    "confirm_downloads": false,
    "confirm_sync": true,
    "confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

    "host": "00.000.000.000",
    "user": "<Username>",
    "port": "22",

    "remote_path": "/var/www/html/",
    "ignore_regexes": [
        "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
        "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
        "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
    ],
    "file_permissions": "755",
    "dir_permissions": "755",

    "connect_timeout": 30,
    "ssh_key_file": "C:/AWS Key Pairs.ppk",
}
```

**Sublime console:**

```
Connecting to SFTP server "00.000.000.000" as "<Username>" ........... failure (Connection timeout)
```

**sublime_sftp_debug.txt:**

```
2022-06-01 00:12:19, SFTP Read:
    Using username "<Username>".
    Server refused our key
    FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

**Remote server's auth.log:**

```
Jun  1 04:12:18 ip-000-00-00-000 sshd[59492]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Jun  1 04:12:18 ip-000-00-00-000 sshd[59492]: Connection closed by authenticating user <Username> 00.00.000.00 port 49161 [preauth]
```

Does anyone happen to have any idea why this problem is occurring?
Before this error, another error was appearing regarding the version of the key generated by PuTTYgen. Maybe it's some other configuration when generating the private key, but I've already tried to follow several different tutorials, and none have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that your server was updated to require rsa-sha2. And Sublime (or your version of it) does not support it yet.

Make sure you have the latest version of Sublime.

If it turns out that Sublime does not support rsa-sha2 yet, you will need to reconfigure your server to allow old "RSA" by adding `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` to `sshd_config`.